# Moving between environments in SharePoint 2010

Tags: web-part

I'm fairly new to SharePoint development so I hope I can explain this clearly.

I am working on a SharePoint project which has the Live and Development sites on the same server.  The sites contain custom web parts which are contained within a single dll.

I need to make some updates to the Live site and also to the web parts.

My plan is to do an export of the Live site, and import it into the Dev site.  Then do the Dev and then either export back into Live or simply switch over the urls so that Dev becomes Live and vice versa.

However, I'm concerned about the web parts.  If I export from Live into Dev, I'm unclear what the impact will be if I update the web part and re-deploy it using Update-SPSolution.  If I do I presume I will also be updating the web part in Live as well, which clearly I don't want to do.

Is there a way that I can update the web parts but only deploy the dll to the Dev site and have Live retain it's current version until I'm ready to roll-out into Live?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

1) your setup is very very wrong! never have live sites mixed with dev on the same server! your asking for trouble!

solution to that issue?

1a) create a virtual machine on your local pc and copy the live enviroment to the virtual machine, if any issue occures it doesnt matter as its on your local pc and on a virtual machine that you can backup once setup and restore is major issues occure.

1b) on the server make it virtualized and have a live enviroment and dev enviroment, seperating the two to minimise error and downtime.

2) current issue, what is the live site? is it a subsite or site collection? if you export its not full fidelity... so your alerts and workflows ect would all be lost! if its at the site collection level you can use backup and restore which is full fidelity and the recommended approach.

seperate the two from each other for the time being! one web application as live and another webapplication for dev. This way you can reset iis for a given webapplication. Updating a webpart will be updating it for all webapplications as your updating the resources and dll in gac making an iisrest on the server. Seperating your dev from live on different servers or having you live only on the server and dev on a virtual pc would overcome this issue!

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I know the setup is wrong, but it's on a customer server so apart from making recommendations there isn't much I can do about that.

I guess one option is to duplicate the web part dll into a dev and live version.  A horrid solution but perhaps the safest.

Comment: if you have the code for the webpart than what you can do is change the version. so the live site will use 1.0.0.0 and the dev site would use 1.0.0.1